# invalid conversion from void* to struct* in C++

Tags: c++, struct, compiler-warnings, void

I have a problem related with this implementation :

```
struct arg_struct
{
    int low;
    int high;
}*args;

void segmentedSieve(void * arguments)
{
    arg_struct *args =  arguments;
 /****do something******/
}
```

I would like to compile the program in C++ because there are several variables that use C++ libraries in it...

the problem here lies on this line :

```
arg_struct *args =  arguments;
```

The compilation fails and compiler says that it's an invalid conversion from void* to struct*...do you know how to solve this issue?? any help is really appreciated..

here is the reproducible result, I use C++ for this :

```
struct arg_struct
{
    int low;
    int high;
}*args;

void request_from_someone(void * arguments)
{
    arg_struct *args =  arguments;
 /****do something******/
}

int main(){
/***nothing to see here, just trying to give a compilation error***/

return 0;
}
```

compilation error :
[image]

Comment: Unlike C, C++ requires an explicit type cast of `void*` to another `T*`.

Comment: Why is it a `void*` in the first place? That's very rarely needed in C++.

Comment: You will have to use [std::bit_cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/bit_cast) (or if you are pre C++20 use the example implementation shown there). Even though you see memcpy it might not emit any extra assembly but it will have defined behavior

Comment: @PepijnKramer `std::bit_cast` likely isn't needed here.  Plain-old `static_cast` is likely all that's needed (assuming the parameter needs to be a `void*` in the first place).

Comment: `void*` is almost certainly wrong there, but you are not giving sufficient context to be sure. Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: @user17732522 see my post again, just copy paste into an editor and save it as .cpp and you will see the compilation error I am talking about

Comment: The comment from @user17732522 asks **why** the code uses `void*`. That's usually a design mistake.

Comment: You are going to need a Thesaurus.  Which `args` do you want to use?  You have `struct arg_struct *args;` at the top of the example and `arg_struct *args` in the function.  They are two separate variables.  You are going to confuse the readers and maybe the compiler.

Comment: I have added the the program and error sample above..I am hopeful you will check it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you need to explicitly cast from `void*` to a real pointer type:

```
arg_struct *args = (arg_struct *)arguments;
```

Comment: Yes it does. If you are unable to write a cast correctly however, you can open another question with the code you did write and ask how to write it correctly. Preferably with an actual error message rather than "it does not work".

Comment: @Deadly Stack Overflow usage note: You never want to write "It does not work." here. It's sort of the kiss of death. Instead you want to state exactly what you observe happening (program behaviour, error messages, warning diagnostics, debugging output like stack traces, and anything else that seems relevant) and what you expected to happen (generally program behaviour. Stating you didn't expect errors or warnings is kinda useless).

Comment: @Blindy I did apply the code into the program above but it still display the same error..I have just posted the error above

Comment: @user4581301 sorry about that, the fault is on me because I haven't slept for almost 2 days just because of this error, perhaps I did that comment half conscious

Comment: @DeadlyKitten999 This fix should've worked. You either didn't save the file, or you need to do it in more than one place.

Answer (score 0):

here is my answer after all of the sleepless nights..but is this correct?
(I am using C++, and I noticed that using C++11 flag will still get the same error again)

```
 arg_struct *args = static_cast<arg_struct*> (arguments);
```

Comment: This is the exact same thing as suggested in the other answer, but spelled in a different way. Yes, this is ok.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat but this one works after I disable the C++11 flags...is there another implementation of this one in C++11?

Comment: This should work regardless of C++11. If it doesn't for you, please provide a [mcve] that doesn't compile in C++11 and compiles in an other version.

Comment: If you only want to fix the compile issue in the question, then yes it is correct. However you should also consider the design issues pointed out by @user17732522. Your edit indicates that you have the same error again in c++11 mode, it is likely due to something else.

Comment: @WeijunZhou yes that solution also works...after some inspections, it is my own compiler which has problems...

Comment: @DeadlyKitten999 The only reason why the above wouldn't work is if you compile in pre -C++11 mode. That is, before `static_assert` was added to the language.